# how to quickly write in MYSQL DB using c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I have an application written in c++ which runs different threads. One thread is responsible for continuously populating a MYSQL database table with millions of rows. I need to optimize this thread such that it insert the data in the shortest time to avoid slowing the other threads.

Here is the table I want to populate,

```
create table Frames
(
id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
f1 varchar(8) not null , 
f2 varchar(6) not null , 
f3 varchar(6) not null , 
f4 varchar(2) not null ,
f5 varchar(4),
f6 varchar(16000),
f7 varchar(4) not null
);
```

And Here is the code I use to populate it

```
#define MAX 8000

MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
char *server = "machine-name";
char *user = "root";
char *password = "";
char *database = "db_name";
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
// Connect to database 
if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
     user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
  return(1);  
}

char rowentry[1000];
for (int c = 0; c < 125; ++c)
{
  stringstream query; 
  query << "insert into Frames (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7) values";
  for (int i = 1; i <= MAX; ++i)
  {
     sprintf ( rowentry, "('AAAAAAAA','000001','000002','05','5005','00000000010000000001000000000100000000010000000001','MKJE')");
     query << rowentry;
     if(i==MAX)
        query << ";";
     else
        query << ",";
  }
  if (mysql_query(conn, query.str().c_str() )) {
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
     return(1);
  }
} 
mysql_close(conn);
```

In the above codes, I used MYISAM as a storage engine for my table.
Then, I populate it with 1 million rows using 125 insert statments.
Each statement inserts 8000 rows at once.
It takes around 7 seconds to finish this task which is very long time in my application.
I also tried InnoDB storage engine which gives me 20 seconds to complete this task.

Can I get a solution to have these one million rows be inserted in the DB in a very short time (around 1-2 seconds) ?

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Beside the use of `stringstream` I don't see C++ code, only C. Step 1: Use RAII for connections. Step 2: Use `std::string` (at least).

Comment: Have you had a look at [sqlpp11](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11)?

Comment: try multi-thread, probably would be better.

Comment: @Torbjörn : This code is just a testbench that i use to test my DB insertion speed. I already removed the stringstream and the code is now purely C .

Comment: @Torbjörn : I dont have problems in c++/mysql interface. My problem is in the mysql DB insertion speed itself . so Is there any optimization in the query or in the mysql server itself to improve this ?

Comment: @TongxuanLiu : Actually , I need to insert my rows in order as they come from the same source, so, how can i benefit from multithreading in this case ?

Comment: @john, is there any relations between the rows? if not you don't need to insert in order...if data is available, just split the tasks based on data such as (0-1000) task 1, (1001-2000) task 2... and so on.

Comment: @TongxuanLiu : And how can these tasks run concurrently ?? you mean different threads in C++ ?

Comment: yes.. split data by tasks, and each thread take multiple tasks to run.